# ValueError: Number of labels=34866 does not match number of samples=2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to run Decision Tree Classifier but I face this problem.Please can you explain me how do I fix this Error?My English isn’t very good but I will try to understand!I'm just starting to learn the program, so please point me out if there's anything that isn't good enough.thank you!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd

sale=pd.read_csv('Online_Sale.csv')
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Microsoft JhengHei']
sale['回購'] = sale['回購'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Y' else 0)
sale['單位售價'] = sale['單位售價'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
x=sale['年紀'],sale['單位售價']
y=sale['回購']

print(x)
print(y)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
model = clf.fit(x, y)

text_representation = tree.export_text(clf)
print(text_representation)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
tree.plot_tree(clf, 
              filled=True)
fig.savefig("decistion_tree.png")
```

data：

[image]

I looked for a lot of different approaches, but I didn't have a way to fully understand what the problem is...

Comment: Instead of `x=sale['年紀'],sale['單位售價']`, do you want `x=sale[['年紀', '單位售價']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a small error with:

```py
x=sale['年紀'],sale['單位售價']
```

Rather than selecting the columns you want, this creates a tuple of the columns, hence the end of the error message `... does not match number of samples=2`

One way to create a new `pd.DataFrame` with your selected columns:

```py
x=sale[['年紀', '單位售價']]
```